# Is there a way to plot/identify a count over time using a list of date ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data similar to the following which shows members, what day they entered a facility, and what day the left the facility, which looks similar to the following

```
member_name   entry_date   exit_date
John          2015-01-01   2020-01-01
Adam          2015-01-01   2019-01-01
Tyler         2016-01-01   2017-01-01
Amy           2017-06-01   2020-01-01
```

I'm wondering if there is any way that I can A.) retrieve a count of how many members are in the facility at a given date (for example, there would be 3 people from the above sample on 2016-06-01) and B.) can I make a linegraph showcasing the count of people per day.  My actual data is more intricate than this where people are coming in and out of the facility every day, so I'd need to be able to identify the number of people in the facility on any given day, rather than month or year.

Comment: a) `count= df.groupby("entry_date").count()` .  b) using matplotlib: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(count)`

Comment: This use case is exactly what [staircase](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/) is for. It's part of the pandas ecosystem and contains a lot of functionality for working with stepfunction data. In particular look at the [queue case study](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/case_studies/queues.html).

Comment: If you dump a more substantial dataset in the question I'll do a worked solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of a specific value on a pandas column (such as a date), you can try:

```
(df['entry-date'] =='2015-01-01').sum()
```

For the line plot of the count you can do:

```
df.groupby('entry-date')['member_name'].count().plot(kind='line');
```